# How to restore WhatsApp messages?

Tags: sms, backup, message, whatsapp, restore

**I don't have backup in my google drive and also don't have backup in my local storage. Is there any way I can restore my messages back in my phone.**

1. I don't have back up in google drive
2. I don't have backup in local storage

Comment: Please add more details about what happend, is there any data on the phone that could be restored? how was it deleted?

Comment: My all messages automatically deleted today morning maybe due to some WhatsApp bug When I open WhatsApp in the morning all chats got deleted. First it was showing a  of notification of WhatsApp error when I was trying to open it then it was taking time to open my WhatsApp then I restarted my phone then  I opened WhatsApp and boom my all messages are mysteriously deleted. I don't know why this happened